# How to pass handle of telnet in python from one classs to other

Tags: python-3.x, telnet

I am creating telnet handle in one class method, Now if I pass that handle to some other method of same class and try to to execute commands, it is not working.
Evrytime I have to connect before executing command from other methods.
Any way to pass the handle, and use it without establishing new connection

```
import telnetlib
import time
import re
import os


class Tel():


    def __init__(self)
        print("inside __init__ of Tel class")
        self.HOST = "ABC"
        self.username = "xyz"
        self.password = "XYZ"
        self.port = "20"

    def open_telnet(self):
        print("Connecting Telnet connection to", self.HOST, "at port", self.port)
        try:
            self.net = telnetlib.Telnet(self.HOST, self.port)
            print("Connected to telnet")
        except:
            print("The telnet conection to",self.HOST,"failed")

        return self.net

    def sendcmd(ne,obj, command):
        cmdoutput = 0
        if obj == None :
            print ("objecy is none IIII")
            obj = ne.open_telnet()
        try:
            obj.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        except:
            print("Not connected")
        print(obj.read_until(b"+> ", 10).decode('ascii'))
        print(cmdoutput)
        return cmdoutput

ne_obj = Tel()
iim = ne_obj.open_telnet()
cmdoutput = ne_obj.sendcmd(iim,"help all") 
print(cmdoutput)
```

SO, I am passing telnet object "iim" to sendcmd method, but it seems it is not able to execute command.
When I call open_telnet method inside sendcmd method and get object of that call then it is working.
But, I dont want to do that, I want to connect once and use that object for other commands, 
Please suggest me some soultion

Comment: hard to say when you dont show any code.

Comment: I am having below code,

Comment: Why do you need to pass it between the command it's already in the class instance which is the first attribute of the method.

Comment: And where do you call the open method of the telnet object as by default telebt object need open called in them to connect.

Comment: I know but its not working for me somehow, I have to call open_telnet method inside sendcmd method, otherwise I am getting blanks in the output.

Comment: I have provided a sample code in the answer below which works. Are you able to replicate you problem using the online host and port from my answer

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the `open_telnet` function at all, the telnet object is already stored as an an attribute in your class instance called net. so just use the class instance to use the telnet object

```py
import telnetlib

class Tel:
    def __init__(self):
        print("inside __init__ of Tel class")
        self.HOST = "towel.blinkenlights.nl"
        self.username = "xyz"
        self.password = "XYZ"
        self.port = "23"
        self.net = telnetlib.Telnet(self.HOST, self.port)

    def sendcmd(self, command):
        self.net.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        response = [text.strip() for text in self.net.read_until(b")", 10).decode('ascii').splitlines()]
        return response

ne_obj = Tel()
cmdoutput = ne_obj.sendcmd("help all")
print(cmdoutput)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
inside __init__ of Tel class
['\x1b[H\x1b[J\x1b[H', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Original Work   : Simon Jansen ( http://www.asciimation.co.nz/ )']
```

Comment: Hi, Can you try some other port, for port 23 it is working for me.